not able to use multiple gateways with AuthorizationPolicy on istio gateway (RBAC: access denied)
I have to use multiple gateways which are namespace wise where as, every namespace has its own AuthorizationPolicy either to allow the traffic or DENY the traffic on IP based block
e.g
my default gateway from istio-system namespace should not have any ip blocklist, it should be open to *.xyz.xyz domain:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: istio-ingressgateway
  name: istio-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: gateway
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - *.xyz.xyz
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      tls:
        httpsRedirect: true
    - hosts:
        - *.xyz.xyz
      port:
        name: https
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        credentialName: tls-wildcard-cert2
        mode: SIMPLE

where as my another application need ip filtering that only allowed ips can access that internal application like:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: canary-gateway
  namespace: canary
spec:
  selector:
    istio: gateway
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - canary.xyz.xyz
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      tls:
        httpsRedirect: true
    - hosts:
        - canary.xyz.xyz
      port:
        name: https
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        credentialName: tls-wildcard-cert2
        mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: canary-ip-whitelist
  namespace: canary
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        ipBlocks: ["45.252.72.179/32", "27.107.31.42/30"]

the matchLabels for my service and deployment is like:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        version: v1
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'true'
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: frontend-test
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
        - name: server
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/microservices-demo/frontend:v0.9.0
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            httpGet:
              path: "/_healthz"
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
              - name: "Cookie"
                value: "shop_session-id=x-readiness-probe"
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            httpGet:
              path: "/_healthz"
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
              - name: "Cookie"
                value: "shop_session-id=x-liveness-probe"
          env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "8080"
          - name: PRODUCT_CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "productcatalogservice:3550"
          - name: CURRENCY_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "currencyservice:7000"
          - name: CART_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "cartservice:7070"
          - name: RECOMMENDATION_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "recommendationservice:8080"
          - name: SHIPPING_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "shippingservice:50051"
          - name: CHECKOUT_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "checkoutservice:5050"
          - name: AD_SERVICE_ADDR
            value: "adservice:9555"
          # # ENV_PLATFORM: One of: local, gcp, aws, azure, onprem, alibaba
          # # When not set, defaults to "local" unless running in GKE, otherwies auto-sets to gcp
          # - name: ENV_PLATFORM
          #   value: "aws"
          - name: ENABLE_PROFILER
            value: "0"
          # - name: CYMBAL_BRANDING
          #   value: "true"
          # - name: FRONTEND_MESSAGE
          #   value: "Replace this with a message you want to display on all pages."
          # As part of an optional Google Cloud demo, you can run an optional microservice called the "packaging service".
          # - name: PACKAGING_SERVICE_URL
          #   value: "" # This value would look like "http://123.123.123"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 64Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 128Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
    service: frontend
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080


i need to configure ip whitelisting and blocklisting for multiple namespaces which has multiple gateways
